# Playing Sound in titanium Error is function not found

Tags: android, audio, web, titanium

Im having trouble just playing a simple sound as the function is undefined. The sound files are in the right spot so I dont know what's going wrong. I am a beginner with this so help is much appreciated.

```
//Level 1 Page
    var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
    var tab = Titanium.UI.currentTab;

    var leveloneview = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%',
        backgroundColor : 'blue',
    });
    var tile1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        bottom : '100',
        width : '100',
        height : '100',
        image : "images/pirate-icon.png",
    });
    var tile2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        left : '50',
        bottom : '100',
        width : '100',
        height : '100',
        image : "images/pirate-icon.png",
    });
    var tile3 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        right : '50',
        bottom : '100',
        width : '100',
        height : '100',
        image : "images/pirate-icon.png",
    });
    var sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({
        url : 'sounds/wheres_me_rum.mp3',
        preload : true
    });
    var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title : 'Click to play sound',
        width : '200',
        height : '40',
        top : 20,
        align:'center',
    });
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        sound.play();
    });

    leveloneview.add(tile1);
    leveloneview.add(tile2);
    leveloneview.add(tile3);
    leveloneview.add(button);
    win.add(leveloneview);
```

Comment: can you add the exact error log?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at /index.html (line 6080)

Comment: I forgot to mention it has only come up with that error since Ti.Media.createsound and button event listener have been added. Before that the .js file would load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at /index.html (line 6080)
```

Ti.Media.Sound is not supported on mobile web. See http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound for supported platforms.

Comment: That is probably my problem. Thank you. Now I've gotta solve my problem that I have on android but works fine on mobile web.